# How to insert a space character between two adjacent delimiters using Unix?

Tags: unix

I have a text file with a given below example.

```
M00214180|M0021418000|00|10007702|153203136600|1|M|02||10232015
M00214180|M0021418000|00|10007702|153203136600|2|M|02||10232015
M00214180|M0021418000|00|10007702|153203429000|1|M|02||10232015
M00214178|M0021417801|01|10007702|153010126800|1|M|02||05122015
M00214163|M0021416301|01|10007702|153080107000|1|M|02||10302015
```

But it should be like below:

```
M00214180|M0021418000|00|10007702|153203136600|1|M|02| |10232015
M00214180|M0021418000|00|10007702|153203136600|2|M|02| |10232015
M00214180|M0021418000|00|10007702|153203429000|1|M|02| |10232015
M00214178|M0021417801|01|10007702|153010126800|1|M|02| |05122015
M00214163|M0021416301|01|10007702|153080107000|1|M|02| |10302015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
sed 's/||/| |/g' your_file.txt
```

If your file has only 1 occurrence of two adjacent delimiters, then you can omit `g` part like below.

```
sed 's/||/| |/' your_file.txt
```

Comment: Might not need the "g" flag, if there's only one replacement.

Comment: If there are more than 1 adjacent delimiters then it would be better to use `g`. Anyways. I will update then answer to mention the same. Thanks

Comment: @Utsav But on some case your command is incorrect as below:                                             04| |500 Plan w/audio| ||,| || |B9710| || |1| || || || || ||
3| |Co Pay 1000 Plan w/audio| ||,| || |M79671|R202|G479| |1| || || || || ||
5| |500 Plan w/audio| ||,| || |B9710| || |1| || || || || ||

Comment: If possible, can you edit the question and show the file and then the output after `sed` command.